# How do i sort a list of lists of vector pairs?

Tags: list-manipulation, vector, sorting

My problem is probably not so difficult but I could not find a solution myself. 
I am doing computations with 4 dimensional vectors, they represent the vertices of a polytope. So the order of the elements within one vector is important. 
If two vectors are in a pair then these will eventually be connected by an edge, the order of the two vectors within such a pair is therefore not important. 
I have a list that contains lists of vector pairs. One list of vector pairs looks similar to the following example: 
`{{{1,2,3,4}, {1,2,4,3}}, {{1,2,3,4}, {1,3,2,4}}, {{2,1,3,4}, {1,3,2,4}}}`
So my list of lists contains a multiple of lists like the example and will look like this:

```
{ 
{{{1,2,3,4}, {1,2,4,3}}, {{1,2,3,4}, {1,3,2,4}}, {{2,1,3,4}, {1,3,2,4}}}, 
{{{...},{...}},{{...},{...}},{{...},{...}}},
{{{...},{...}},{{...},{...}},{{...},{...}}},
{{{...},{...}},{{...},{...}},{{...},{...}}},
...
}
```

However I will do some reflections on the list of vector pairs (first example) and find "images" of the list of the same form. Sometimes such "images" will contain the same vector pairs. I know how to check if the "image" i found is already contained in my big list. 
But, here comes my problem, this checking does not work if the vector pairs are in a different order.
So it will not recognize `{{{1,2,3,4}, {1,2,4,3}}, {{1,2,3,4}, {1,3,2,4}}, {{1,3,2,4},{2,1,3,4}}}` as being already contained in my big list even though the vector pairs are exactly the same but the order of the last pair is different.
I use `Sort[]` on the smaller lists, which is needed, but this only sorts the pairs of vectors and does not sort the vectors within a pair.
How do I sort lists within a list?

Comment: _"...and does not sort the vectors within a pair."_  but you said earlier at the top that _"... the order of the elements within one vector is important."_ so do you want to sort the vectors or the pairs? If you want to sort the vectors you do `Map[Sort, edges, {2}]` (at level 2). This gives `{{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 
   3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}}`. If you want to sort the pairs you do `Map[Sort, edges, {1}]` (at level 1).

Comment: I do not want to sort the vectors, the order of the elements of a vector is very important. Thank you `Map[Sort, edges,{1}]` is what i was looking for.

Comment: `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Order @@@ # &]@edges` or `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Ordering /@ # &]@edges` or  `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort/@# &]@edges`?